# How to recognize dashed commands from Console user input?

Tags: c#

let's say user enters `-path D:\TestFolder\Test.txt -output c -formula x+1-20` in console.
That means he wants to process file which is located in that path, output results to console and apply that formula to each number in file.

what is the proper way to recognize commands if they start with dash?

for example I want to build an object from that string:

```
public UserInput(string input)
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string OutputParam { get; set; }
        public string Formula { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please, have a look at `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-5.0 You'll get `{"-path", @"D:\TestFolder\Test.txt", "-output", "c", "-formula", "x+1-20"}` array

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, there are lots of ways to parse a command line. I would suggest searching online for different methods, trying something yourself, and coming back with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target framework, and depending on the complexity of the input parameters, you may want to consider using a 3rd party package to do the parsing for you. There are plenty to choose from each with their own quirks and best use cases (e.g. one example is [Command Line Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) which can work with .NET Standard. If you are using .NET Core, there is a built in [System.CommandLine](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) that can do what you need as well). Each of these will have their own particular implementations and specifics on how to use, so showing examples might not be as helpful if you're not interested in parsing complex user input.

If you are specifically simply trying to parse only the string `-path <path> -output <file> -formula <formula>`, you could simply write a helper function to return an array of values after parsing, rather than creating a class (and having to deal with `static` and all that in your `Main` function). If you want to create a custom class to handle things like mapping your mathematical formula to something, or manipulate the data in some way, you should probably refactor the example below.

Helper:

```
private static string[] ParseInput(string[] input)
{
    try
    {
        var results = new string[3];        

        // shift over one index based on the position of the arguments
        // get the 'path' value
        var index = input.FindIndex(x => x == "-path") + 1;
        results[0] = input[index];

        // get the 'output' value
        index = input.FindIndex(x => x == "-output") + 1;
        results[1] = input[index];

        // get the formula value
        index = input.FindIndex(x => x == "-formula") + 1;
        results[2] = input[index];

        return results;
    }
    catch { throw new ArgumentException("Input string was not formatted correctly.")
}
```

You can then use this in the main program:

```
...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        var results = ParseInput(args);
        // do stuff with results[0] through [2]
        ...
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Note:** In general I would avoid hardcoding stuff like this, because it makes your application nearly impossible to extend as you get new requirements. For example, if you ever decide you want a `-formula2` input argument, well now you need to recode your entire helper function, and any dependencies to consume that information. On the flip side, I also do not advise to install large 3rd party packages that "do everything" if you have a very specific requirement that (you assume) will never change. On this one it's really up to your requirements and scope to decide if you need to use a larger solution to solve your problem.